# How to make the transition from Territory Management 1 to 2?

Tags: territory-management

In our org we use TM 1. We want to switch to Lightning Experience, and for that we need to switch to TM 2, also known as Enterprise Territory Management.

It looks like this is not an easy thing to do. The first required step is to have Salesforce disable Customizable Forecasting. But this requires the disabling of TM 1. So for a while we would be stuck without any TM at all.

Has anyone else made the transition? How did you do it?

Comment: I think this question would receive a much better answer if asked in the Trailblazer Community. It's very broad question that's not well suited to out format here on SF.SE. It's likely to need a lot of back and forth discussion. It's for that reason that I've voted to close this question. (Its not that it isn't a good question.)